# Алгоритм создания нового массива vector C++

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм, строки, vector

Есть массив `masiv_Y1 = {{A, ADF}, {B, BCF}, {C, BC}, {D, ADF}, {E, E}, {F, ABDF}}`

С помощью операций объединения и пересечения всех возможных пар массива надо создать 
`masiv_Y2 = {{AB, F}, {AD, ADF}, {AF, ADF}, {BC, BC}, {BD, F}, {BF, BF}, {CF, B}, {DF, ADF}}`

Если `masiv_Y1[x][1]` имеет общие элементы с `masiv_Y1[y][1]` (при условии что `x != y` ) то элементы нового массива будут:

`masiv_Y2 [z][0] = объединения (masiv_Y1[x][0] и masiv_Y1[y][0]); 
masiv_Y2 [z][1] = пересечения (masiv_Y1[x][1] и masiv_Y1[y][1]);`

Помогите исправить алгоритм! Также я хочу удалить повторяющиеся элементы в каждой новой строке... (функция `symbols()`)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<std::string> String1D;
typedef std::vector<String1D> String2D;

string symbols(string);

int main()
{
String2D masiv_Y1(6, String1D(2));
masiv_Y1[0][0]="A";
masiv_Y1[0][1]="ADF";
masiv_Y1[1][0]="B";
masiv_Y1[1][1]="BCF";
masiv_Y1[2][0]="C";
masiv_Y1[2][1]="BC";
masiv_Y1[3][0]="D";
masiv_Y1[3][1]="ADF";
masiv_Y1[2][0]="E";
masiv_Y1[2][1]="E";
masiv_Y1[3][0]="F";
masiv_Y1[3][1]="ABDF";

String2D masiv_Y2 (masiv_Y1.size() * masiv_Y1.size(), String1D(2));
int kapa = 0;
size_t k = 0;
do {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < masiv_Y1.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < masiv_Y1.size(); j++)
        {
            for (size_t g = 0; g < masiv_Y1[i][1].size(); g++)
            {
                for (size_t h = 0; h < masiv_Y1[j][1].size(); h++)
                {
                    if (masiv_Y1[i][1][g] == masiv_Y1[j][1][h])
                    {
                        kapa++;
                        masiv_Y2[k][1] = masiv_Y2[k][1] + masiv_Y1[i][1][g];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (kapa != 0) masiv_Y2[k][0] = masiv_Y1[i][0] + masiv_Y1[j][0];
            kapa = 0;
            k++;
        }
    }
} while (k < 1);


for (size_t i = 0; i < masiv_Y2.size(); i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        sort(masiv_Y2[i][j].begin(), masiv_Y2[i][j].end());
        //I want to remove duplicate symbols
        //masiv_Y2[i][j] = symbols(masiv_Y2[i][j]);
    }
}

String2D::iterator iter;
sort(masiv_Y2.begin( ), masiv_Y2.end( ));
iter = unique(masiv_Y2.begin(), masiv_Y2.end());
masiv_Y2.resize(iter - masiv_Y2.begin());

cout<<endl;
cout<<"masiv_Y2"<<endl<<endl;
String2D::iterator iter1 = masiv_Y2.begin();
while (iter1 != masiv_Y2.end())
{
    std::copy((*iter1).begin(), (*iter1).end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(cout, " "));
    cout << "\n";
    ++iter1;
} }

string symbols(string str)
{
string str1 = "" + str[0];
for (size_t i = 1; i < str.size(); i++)
{
    if (str[i] != str[i-1])
    {
        str1 += str[i];
    }
}
return str1; }
```

Comment: Не понятен принцип создания элементов нового массива. Опишите его.

Comment: Если masiv_Y1[x][1] имеет общие элементы с masiv_Y1[y][1] (при условии что x != y ) то элементы нового массива будут: `masiv_Y2 [z][0] = объединения (masiv_Y1[x][0] и masiv_Y1[y][0]) ; masiv_Y2 [z][1] = пересечения (masiv_Y1[x][1] и masiv_Y1[y][1])`

Comment: То есть новый массив это объединения и пересечения пар элементов всех возможных комбинаций старого массива

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если предположить, что строки в элементах внутреннего вектора сортированы, то можно к ним применить стандартные алгоритмы `std::set_intersection` и `std::set_union`.

Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> masiv_Y1 = 
    {
        { "A", "ADF" }, { "B", "BCF" }, { "C", "BC" }, 
        { "D", "ADF" }, { "E", "E" }, { "F", "ABDF" }
    };

    for ( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p : masiv_Y1 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> masiv_Y2;

    for ( auto current = masiv_Y1.begin(); current != masiv_Y1.end(); ++current )
    {
        for ( auto next = std::next( current ); next != masiv_Y1.end(); ++next )
        {
            std::string second;

            std::set_intersection( current->second.begin(), current->second.end(),
                                   next->second.begin(), next->second.end(),
                                   std::back_inserter( second ) );
            if ( !second.empty() )
            {
                std::string first;
                std::set_union( current->first.begin(), current->first.end(),
                                next->first.begin(), next->first.end(),
                                std::back_inserter( first ) );

                masiv_Y2.push_back( { first, second } );                                
            }
        }
    }

    for ( const std::pair<std::string, std::string> &p : masiv_Y2 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
{ A, ADF } { B, BCF } { C, BC } { D, ADF } { E, E } { F, ABDF } 
{ AB, F } { AD, ADF } { AF, ADF } { BC, BC } { BD, F } { BF, BF } { CF, B } { DF, ADF }
```

При использовании ваших контейнеров, то есть вложенных векторов, программа может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    typedef std::vector<std::string> String1D;
    typedef std::vector<String1D> String2D;

    String2D masiv_Y1 = 
    {
        { "A", "ADF" }, { "B", "BCF" }, { "C", "BC" }, 
        { "D", "ADF" }, { "E", "E" }, { "F", "ABDF" }
    };

    for ( const String1D &p : masiv_Y1 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;


    String2D masiv_Y2;

    for ( auto current = masiv_Y1.begin(); current != masiv_Y1.end(); ++current )
    {
        for ( auto next = std::next( current ); next != masiv_Y1.end(); ++next )
        {
            std::string second;

            std::set_intersection( ( *current )[1].begin(), ( *current )[1].end(),
                                   ( *next )[1].begin(), ( *next )[1].end(),
                                   std::back_inserter( second ) );
            if ( !second.empty() )
            {
                std::string first;
                std::set_union( ( *current )[0].begin(), ( *current )[0].end(),
                                ( *next )[0].begin(), ( *next )[0].end(),
                                std::back_inserter( first ) );

                masiv_Y2.push_back( { first, second } );                                
            }
        }
    }

    for ( const String1D &p : masiv_Y2 )
    {
        std::cout << "{ " << p[0] << ", " << p[1] << " } ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отличный вариант

Comment: @Merk30 Используйте вместо std::pair свой вектор std::vector<std::string>.

Comment: @Merk30 Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! лабораторную по теории графов закончил :)